# NodeJS: How to get objects with variable child properties with MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, backend

I am trying to get an array of documents where a child property is `true`. Here's some code:

```
public static getTeams(req, res) {
    // Initialize a connection to the database
    Globals.initDb(res).then((db: Db) => {
        // Reference a collection in the Database
        db.collection('teams', (error: Error, collection: Collection) => {
            // Check if an error occured getting the collection
            Globals.checkError({ error, result: collection, res }).then(() => {
                // find teams that a user administrates
                collection.find(
                    { 'usergroups.users': { [req.params.id]: true } },
                    { name: 1, icon: 1, type: 1, thumbnail: 1 }
                ).toArray((err, teams: Array<{ name: string, icon: string }>) => {
                    // make sure that went through OK
                    Globals.checkError({ error: err, result: teams, res }).then(() => {
                        if (!teams[0]) {
                            teams = [];
                        }
                        res.status(200).json(teams);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

`checkError` is just a function I wrote to make it easier to check for errors, and it works fine, I checked it. I am trying to access an array of teams where the `usergroups.users.#userId#` is true. So if your id was j4k53, `usergroups.users.j4k53` is true.

However, when it is true for multiple IDs, the documents are not returned. For example, if `j4k53` and `lfk3m` are both true, it gets returned for neither of them.

Thank you for your help. (This is node with typescript, so it may look a little funky if you are not familiar with TS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it: you can write it like this:

```
{ ['usergroups.users.' + req.params.id]: true}
```

Good luck to anyone who finds this useful!